# Proof for greedy algorithm on doubling currency?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming, programming

I have a currency where each subsequent coin is twice as valuable as the one before it.

I need to prove that for any amount of change needed, the greedy algorithm for making change (always choosing largest amount first than using the next largest and so on) will give the minimum amount of change.

Either that or I need to show that the algorithm wouldn't work by giving a counterexample.

How can I write a proof for this?

Comment: Each coin is *exactly* twice the value of the previous? That's a special case of [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433735), though you can try to simplify the write-up in this case.

Comment: Can you prove each of these.  1) the greedy algorithm will never allocate two coins of the same denomination.  2) Any allocation with two coins of the same denomination is sub optimal. 3) Any representation using 0 or 1 coin in each place holder is unique.