# Coin system problem, perhaps an old one

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say that we have coins with values $1=a_1<a_2<\ldots$ For euros, omitting cents, we have $(1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500)$. The point is that, given a quantity $N$ of money, the bast way to collect it with the least number of coins or notes is taking the largest coin or note of value $x_1$ that is not greater than $N$, and repeat the algorithm with $N-x_1$ and so for, until we get $0$.

This is harder to explain than to do it.

My question is: What condition have to meet the numbers $a_1, a_2,\ldots$ to let work that algorithm?

Is it possible (with that algorithm) to pay any amount if the coins or notes are $(1,7,11,73)$?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking "for which collections of coin values $\{a_i\}$ can we be sure that any value can be realized?  But of course $1$ has to be in your collection and if you have $1$ you have everything.  So...what's the question?  Are you asking "for which collections does the greedy algorithm always get the smallest representation"?  Something else?

Comment: Your suggested algorithm is called a "greedy algorithm". You get a lot of hits and information if you try googling something like: greedy algorithm for coin change problem

Comment: This is called a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). Your question can be rephrased as: Under what conditions on $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ does the greedy algorithm always come up with the (or an) optimal solution? Your specific problem is treated in Wikipedia's [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). That article provides a [link](https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.orl.2004.06.001) to a paper that gives an explicit polynomial-time algorithm to answer your question; unfortunately it is not open-access.

Comment: It's clear, of course that the greedy algorithm isn't always optimal.  If, say, we had $\{1, 10, 15\}$ and wanted to realize $20$ the best is two $10's$.  Not one $15$ and five $1's$.

Comment: But it's hard to follow what you wrote. Your last line asks only about possibility not optimality.  Of course the greedy algorithm always gives some answer (since $1$ has to be in the list), it's just not always optimal.  In your case, $14$ is best realized through two $7's$, not an $11$ and three $1's$.

Comment: I don't understand your final question. As long as $a_1=1$, you can obviously make any amount, whatever algorithm you start with.

Comment: There is a good question hiding in the confusion: what properties does the collection $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_r$ have to have in order for the greedy algorithm to be optimal (optimal in the sense of always requiring the minimal number of coins)? Surely there is already a substantial literature on this question. https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/handouts/120%20Guide%20to%20Greedy%20Algorithms.pdf might be helpful, though it deals in generalities, not specifics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433735/proving-that-greedy-coin-change-algorithm-gives-optimal-solution-under-certain-c gives some conditions, but I think it doesn't completely solve the problem. There is a lot of information at https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0400.pdf but I get the impression that a complete solution is out of reach. Many more discussions can be found by searching for *greedy coin change algorithm*.